# Highcharts polar background color

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is it possible to color the background of the circular part of a Highcharts polar chart? `backgroundColor` colors the background of the entire chart and `plotBackgroundColor` colors the background of the entire plot area. Here's an [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qe8q8/) illustrating the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the pane backgroundColor

```
    pane : {
        background : {
            backgroundColor:"rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)"
        }
    },
```

http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/47-ranges-polar-charts-and-gauges-released

http://jsfiddle.net/thbC9/

Comment: Awesome, that worked perfectly! Can you tell me how to change the border around the chart as well?

Comment: The info is on that same page.  You can set borderColor and borderWidth: pane.background - An object, or array of objects, for backgrounds. Sub options include backgroundColor (which can be solid or gradient),innerWidth, outerWidth, borderWidth, borderColor.